# PrimeFaces ajax update is not triggered when required input field becomes empty

Tags: validation, jsf, input, primefaces, xhtml

I am using JSF with PrimeFaces with fields like below.

```
    <p:outputLabel for="vehicle" value="#{msg['vehicle.text']}" />
    <p:autoComplete id="vehicle" value="#{newCtrlr.vehicleId.vehicle}" autocomplete="true" scrollHeight = "200" required = "true" 
    completeMethod="#{newCtrlr.vehicle_AutoComplete}"  minQueryLength = "2">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener = "#{newCtrlr.onVehicleChange}" update = "market" />
    <p:ajax event="change" listener = "#{newCtrlr.onVehicleChange}" update = "market" />                                        
    </p:autoComplete>

    <p:outputLabel for="market" value="#{msg['market.text']}" />
    <p:inputText id="market" value="#{newCtrlr.market.marketName}"  
    readonly = "#{empty newCtrlr.vehicleId.vehicle ? 'true' :'false' }" />
```

In the above code, if the vehicle value is entered, the market should be made editable. If the vehicle value is cleared, the market should become readonly. Now since the vehicle input is 'required', the ajax update is not triggered and so the market remains enabled. If I remove the 'required' on Vehicle, everything works fine. I would like to know if there is a way to make the inputText required as well as trigger the ajax update when the value is changed to empty/null in the required field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this behavior is default JSF behavior: If the input in invalid, it is not written to the model.
So you have to change this behavior manually, for example with an Event-Listener.

Add the following method to your Backing-Bean:

```
public void setModelValueToNullIfValidationFailed(ComponentSystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
    UIInput input = (UIInput) event.getComponent();
    if (input.isValid()) {
            return;
    }
    input.getValueExpression("value").setValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), null);
}
```

This method checks if the validation of the component has failed. If so the model value is set to null.

Add f:event to your p:autoComplete:

```
<p:autoComplete ...>
    ...
    <f:event type="postValidate" listener="#{newCtrlr.setModelValueToNullIfValidationFailed}" />
</p:autoComplete>
```